# Android: Frequency of location updates from location manager

Tags: android, frequency, android-location, android-gps

Apologies if this is a very mundane or simple issue.

I wrote a location listener class for my android device and set the requestupdate as follows:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

I see the GPS icon come up, blink and then hold steady. In my log, I see location updates, but the problem is there are very few updates, maybe once in 30 seconds or once a minute sometimes (while driving in my car).

Is this normal? Is there any way to get a higher frequency?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as i know it depends on the phone, signal and the accuracy that you request...

```
Criteria locationCriteria = new Criteria();
locationCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.getBestProvider(locationCriteria, true), 0, 0, currentLocationListener);
```

Here's the code i used, it worked pretty fast on my phone.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried using the Criteria. Maybe its just my phone...I shold try it on a different phone..